# What to do when an OP isn't accepting answers that address the question without providing a reason

Tags: discussion

#### Disclaimer upfront - I am involved in the example in which I provide

Take [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90884/why-is-worf-permitted-to-wear-his-sash-but-ro-cant-wear-her-earpiece) as an example.  There are two equally valid answers which address the question the way it has been presented, yet the OP doesn't want to accept any of them.  The OP has checked in on this site recently and it has been [over a week](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/what-is-a-good-time-to-wait-before-accepting-an-answer) (not that I'm saying that is a hard and fast rule, but rather more of a reasonable time frame).

Now, I'm not trying to single out this particular question to force the issue, more trying to understand what to do as a general rule when this situation arises.

When we have a situation as above where there are answers which adequately address the question and the OP doesn't explain what they don't like about the answer, **how do we handle such a situation**, considering this site is about trying to answer people's questions?  Perhaps I'm being a bit grumpy...

Comment: `At this time, there are two different answers, and neither is 100% convincing` - I have a year-and-a-half old question I've not accepted answers for, for pretty much the same reason...

Comment: @Izkata You have my utmost sympathy.  I find it's really annoying when questions are asked but there is no good reason for an answer not being accepted provided

Comment: We really don't know why an OP is not accepting any answer unless he/she tells us. Assuming it's due to some nefarious or obstinate reason probably isn't useful. I have quite a few questions for which I haven't accepted answers -- some well over a year old -- because I'm not satisfied with the answers given so far, but that doesn't mean the same is true for everybody. My $0.02! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess yes point taken. It's just that when the OP fails to explain why they haven't accepted an answer it's really annoying for the answerers

Comment: And, conversely, the OP may well be really annoyed at being harassed over why he/she hasn't picked an answer yet. The users providing answers will indeed live without knowing the reasoning behind the OP's failure to pick an answer. Courtesy goes both ways. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In specific

Both of these answers are opinion-based. That's not to say that they're not good and interesting answers but neither actually offers a *definitive* statement that says (for example)

> "In a later episode, Picard said "*Sashes are fine, Mr Riker, but earrings are not*' "

or

> Rick Berman stated that "*Riker finds Ro's earring unacceptable because he's insensitive*".

As such the OP is probably right to hold out for a better answer (if one exists)

---

### In general

We're back to the old question of when/why users [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). The short version is that an OP is welcome to accept (or not) for whatever reason they choose, whenever they choose.

Your answer might be the best possible with multiple quotes from the script, writer, director, actors, producer, novel and graphic novel and **still not get accepted**. Them's the breaks, I'm afraid.

You're welcome to campaign for an acceptance (I regularly give users a prod to say something like

> "*I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything you'd
>   like me to address before you offer an acceptance?"*

but I also accept that when I do so, sometime I get a) feedback that requires me to rewrite my answer or b) silence.