# What's the etiquette for selecting and answer in this question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

This question [What is the inspiration for Moff?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103913/46509)

Has some answers, a combination of which answer it really. What is the etiquette when it comes to marking one as the answer (I don't think any one answer fully answers it but they're all pretty much the same)

Do I select the oldest? The one with most references etc?

Comment: if none of the questions, in your opinion, answers the question, don't accept any. someone will eventually come along and improve their answer :)

Comment: If none of the answers, in your opinion, answers the question, don't accept any.  Someone will eventually come along and improve their answer :)

Comment: See: [Is it okay to not select an answer as correct?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/876/21267) and [I can't decide which answer to choose; What do I do?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3615/21267)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision is entirely up to you.

The [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) says (emphasis added):

> To accept an answer:
>
> - Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
> - To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
> - You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.
>
> **Accepting an answer is not mandatory**; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

It also [says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) (emphasis added):

> **Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly.** It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

You don't have to accept an answer, or you can accept one using whatever criteria you want (oldest, most references, highest voted, best written, etc.). Either way, you can also ask the answer authors to try to improve their answer to make it stand out as the most acceptable.

Even if you choose to accept an answer, [you may choose to wait before accepting in the hope that a better one will come along](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5065/31936).